# Beforeunload is not detected

Tags: javascript, browser

I am following this code

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
   // Cancel the event
   e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always 
   be shown
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
 });
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

My code is:

```
<body style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden" onload="return onBodyLoad();">
function onBodyLoad() {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
            alert(1);
            document.getElementById("Button1").click();
        });
    }
```

I am closing a tab by clicking on the X. My code is not executing. Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: you're following code ... except you didn't `e.preventDefault();` nor `e.returnValue = '';` - if you followed the instructions, your code would work as expected

Comment: But my point is that "beforeunload" is not detected. No Alert comes up.

Comment: my point is that you didn't follow instructions - so it won't (and alerts WONT ever happen regardless of the choice made, by the way, at least not in Firefox)

Comment: Yes, that event doesn't show a modal window, use `console.log(1)`, you'll see the event is fired. More or less all the "unload" events, including `visibilitychange` are not  following the specs across the browsers. They might not fire, they might not show any alerts, they just might do what ever a browser vendor has invented. If there's not a big must, don't try to intervent the unload events.

Comment: I guess the big question is ... why you want to intercept beforeunload? what is the point of `document.getElementById("Button1").click();` ... perhaps `sendBeacon` can do what you want ...

Comment: It is a big must. When new tab is opened a server side process kicks in. I need to kill it if a user closes the tab before the process completes.

Comment: `sendBeacon` is the best bet then - depending on what action `document.getElementById("Button1").click();` takes ... does it make a request of the server?

Comment: Button1 executes a metod in the code behind that would kill the process.

Comment: `executes a metod in the code behind` - so it sends a request to the server

Comment: Well, yes. I cannot find any other way to kill the process.

Comment: A cross-browser detection of when a user leaves a page is [almost impossible](https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/). If exiting a server-side process depends on this, I'd suggest you to change the design.

Comment: But I cannot get it detected in any Browser. How come? All these samples I saw showing same code. So, none of them are not working today?

Comment: `beforeunload` is fired on many browsers, but modal windows are not popped up, that is also said in the MDN article you've linked to in your question: "_In some browsers, calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() may be ignored during this event._"

Comment: I dont care about Alert. It's just for the testing. What else is not firing is the method test that is attached to the button: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="test" />

Comment: Yes, that's an asynchronous task, they're not executed in (before)unload handlers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Boy, I am in trouble.

Comment: `sendBeacon` Bravo suggested would fix that, but you can't rely on unload events to fire. Those events are just a mess. The igvita.com article I've linked is a bit old, but Chromium-based browsers are still buggy with visibilityChange events, unless fixed very recently.

Comment: I am not even sure how to use sendBeacon for my case. I need to execute a method in the code behind to kill the process. Any dea how to use sendBeacon for that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with asp, but you can read the beacon docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: I did, can't see how to use it for my case.